# Is there a name for this pattern of sealing base classes to a strict set?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, object-oriented-design

In C#, it's possible to create a strictly sealed set of classes that inherit from a base that cannot be further extended like so:

```cs
public abstract record MyBase
{
    public sealed record A: MyBase;
    public sealed record B: MyBase;
    public sealed record C: MyBase;

    private MyBase() { }

    // My base props
}
```

`MyBase` can't be extended (by non-nested classes) because of the private constructor, and the other nested types can't be extended because they're sealed.

This allows you to use the type system to dictate control decisions with the confidence that some cowboy isn't going to come along and add a subclass that breaks everything.

It almost feels similar to rust's enums.

This has proven very useful in my current workflow, but is there a name for this pattern?

Comment: Why would this be a pattern rather than the application of two intentional language features?

Comment: @Flater - A pattern is the application of several intentional language features...

Comment: patterns tend to get named when they are used _for_ something. Perhaps if you tell us what you found this pattern useful for?

Comment: @Ewan - So my actual class represents some email settings (to, from, replyto, subject, template etc.). I'm using the derived types to represent what type of email (and therefore what settings) are being used. So `A` could be `ConfirmationEmail` and `B` could be `PasswordReset`. This is in lieu of putting an `EmailType` enum and just having the one class. So what I've essentially created (at least I think so) is an enum with associated data.

Comment: whats the idea behind preventing anyone making more email types?

Comment: @Ewan - Because only certain types exist and are configurable in our interface and in our database. If they want to add one, they can, they'll just have to edit this class which will force them to think about it more than just thinking all they have to do is inherit from the base. I see it no different to forcing them to add an extra value to an enum

Comment: hmm no sorry, the nearest I can think of is in the builder pattern, where you want to have a series of interfaces returned to force a fluent  style interface and restrict build order.

Comment: @ScottishTapWater: a meal/dish is made from food but that doesn't mean you can point at a vegetable and ask "what dish is this?". I also disagree that a pattern is defined as a sum of any language features it might use. It is correlation, not causation. A pattern describes a certain structured approach. Different languages can implement the approach differently. This is the same as claiming that a story is defined by the words that are used to write it. That is only partially true, you can tell the same story using different words (but not just _any_ words either)

Comment: Being only slightly cheeky, I would say the design pattern here is the emulation of features or concepts for which the C# language has no manifest support. Here, discriminated unions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about a *pattern*, but it looks like you're trying to implement an [algebraic data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type) (to be precise, a sum type). These are very popular particularly in functional languages, which will often have first-order support for them in terms of syntax, pattern matching and compiler exhaustiveness checking. The fact that C# doesn't have first-order support for them means you have to describe them in a slightly roundabout way (via abstract class + private constructor), won't get all the benefits, and using them may not be entirely idiomatic in the language.

The reason I say I'm not sure about calling this a *pattern* is that in languages that have this, it's just a normal language feature. Calling it a pattern would feel a little like calling inheritance from an interface a pattern in C#.

Comment: https://spencerfarley.com/2021/03/26/unions-in-csharp/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this counts as a pattern *per se*, but it *looks* like an implementation of an [Enum class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/enumeration-classes-over-enum-types) which is a way of having java-like enums in languages that don't directly support them (like C#.)

Depending on how you use this class, a possible pattern would be the [strategy pattern](https://dev.to/masreis/strategy-design-pattern-with-java-enum-1am0). As an Example:

```
Public class ThingDoer 
{

  public OtherClass Foo;
  public void DoTheThing(MyBase strategy)
  {
     //common stuff to do before doing the thing...
     strategy.DoTheThing(this.Foo);
     // maybe some more stuff...    
  }
}
//and then later...
MyBase leetStrat = new MyBase.A();
MyFoo = MyDoer.DoTheThing(leetStrat);
```